# Running LLVM file, generated with rustc, with clang

Tags: rust, llvm, llvm-clang

I'm trying to run a `.ll` file with clang and getting linker errors. I have a file `test.rs` that simply includes a main function with a `println!` statement. I generate the LLVM IR with the command `rustc --emit=llvm-ir --crate-type=bin test.rs`. When I try to run the output `test.ll` file with `clang test.ll` I get a linker error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "std::io::stdio::_print::h178318b95760562a", referenced from:
      rust_test::main::h84a9713c734a1b45 in rust_test-9ea667.o
  "_main", referenced from:
     implicit entry/start for main executable
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

So I figured clang couldn't find the Rust libraries and attempted to provide a path to them with the command `clang -L$HOME/.rustup/toolchains/<arch>/lib test.ll` but I receive the same error.

---

The goal here is to create a couple functions in Rust that I will call from LLVM, so I'll have a custom `file.ll` that will use functions that the Rust LLVM IR will provide. I noticed that `rustc` has a `crate-type` command-line argument called `staticlib` and tried to use that as well but to no avail.

Comment: You need to link Rust's libraries. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42626498/598057) for inspiration.

Comment: Use `-l` flag to actually link libraries.

Comment: @StanislavPankevich hmm, seems like that didn't work for me I did `clang -L/Users/JonCatanio/.rustup/toolchains/<arch>/lib test.ll -lstd-826c8d3b356e180c`

Comment: *Why* use LLVM IR instead of just creating an object file and linking it as normal?

Comment: @Shepmaster I was writing a library in Rust that provides an FFI allowing custom LLVM to call into Rust. I'm working on writing a compiler for Python in Rust and wanted to offload some of the work to a library so I don't have to generate a ton of LLVM. I realize now that I wasn't approaching it properly and found these as reference to help me:

[tutorial](http://zsiciarz.github.io/24daysofrust/book/vol1/day23.html)
[FFI info in the Rust book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/first-edition/ffi.html)