# Rust object file missing when linking with C using clang

Tags: rust, linker, clang

I trying to work though some simple FFI things to figure out how to get Rust to work with C or C++ code. My immediate question is:

It seems when I compile Rust code to an object file, it is missing some of the bindings for the clang linker to finalize an executable. Here are two very simple files that I am using.

**clink.c**

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int rust_int(int);
bool rust_bool(int, int);

/********************************/
/* void rust_char_star(char *); */
/********************************/

int main(void) {
    printf("%d\n", rust_int(5));
    if (rust_bool(5, 6)) {
        printf("True\n");
    }
    else { printf("False\n"); }

    /******************************/
    /* rust_char_star("Testing"); */
    /******************************/

    return 0;
}
```

**rustlink.rs**

```
use std::os::raw::{c_int, c_char};
// use std::ffi::{CStr, CString};

#[no_mangle]
pub extern "C" fn rust_int(i: c_int) -> c_int {
    i
}

#[no_mangle]
pub extern "C" fn rust_bool(x: c_int, y: c_int) -> bool {
    if x > y {
        true
    }
    else {
        false
    }
}

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// #[no_mangle]                                                           //
// pub extern "C" fn rust_char_star(c: *const c_char) {                   //
//     let str_printable = unsafe {CString::from_raw(c as *mut c_char) }; //
//                                                                        //
//     println!("{:?}", str_printable);                                   //
// }                                                                      //
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

When I compile each of these without the `CString`, everything works as expected. Ignore the warning.

```
~/dev/rust/learn/clink$ rustc --emit obj --crate-type staticlib rustlink.rs
warning: unused import: `c_char`
use std::os::raw::{c_int, c_char};
                          ^^^^^^
= note: #[warn(unused_imports)] on by default

~/dev/rust/learn/clink$ clang clink.c rustlink.o -o test
~/dev/rust/learn/clink$ ./test
5
False
```

When I uncomment all the code to use the type `CString` though, that's where I'm missing something. I'm not going to repost the above code with the comments removed. Here is what the output yields though.

```
~/dev/rust/learn/clink$ rustc --emit obj --crate-type staticlib rustlink.rs 
warning: unused import: `CStr`
 --> rustlink.rs:2:16
  |
2 | use std::ffi::{CStr, CString};
  |                ^^^^
  |
  = note: #[warn(unused_imports)] on by default

~/dev/rust/learn/clink$ clang clink.c rustlink.o -o test
rustlink.o: In function `alloc::alloc::dealloc':
rustlink.3a1fbbbh-cgu.0:(.text._ZN5alloc5alloc7dealloc17hca8aab9ecdf50cafE+0x43): undefined reference to `__rust_dealloc'
rustlink.o: In function `rust_char_star':
rustlink.3a1fbbbh-cgu.0:(.text.rust_char_star+0xa): undefined reference to `std::ffi::c_str::CString::from_raw'
rustlink.3a1fbbbh-cgu.0:(.text.rust_char_star+0x3a): undefined reference to `<std::ffi::c_str::CString as core::fmt::Debug>::fmt'
rustlink.3a1fbbbh-cgu.0:(.text.rust_char_star+0xa9): undefined reference to `std::io::stdio::_print'
rustlink.o:(.data.DW.ref.rust_eh_personality[DW.ref.rust_eh_personality]+0x0): undefined reference to `rust_eh_personality'
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
~/dev/rust/learn/clink$
```

Going a little further. I attempted to compile the Rust code to a static library to be fed into clang. I'm uncertain why, but this is the result.

```
~/dev/rust/learn/clink$ rustc --crate-type staticlib rustlink.rs 
warning: unused import: `CStr`
 --> rustlink.rs:2:16
  |
2 | use std::ffi::{CStr, CString};
  |                ^^^^
  |
  = note: #[warn(unused_imports)] on by default

~/dev/rust/learn/clink$ ls
clink.c  librustlink.a  rustlink.o  rustlink.rs
~/dev/rust/learn/clink$ clang clink.c -o test -lrustlink
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lrustlink
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
~/dev/rust/learn/clink$ clang clink.c -o test -L -lrustlink
/tmp/clink-357672.o: In function `main':
clink.c:(.text+0x15): undefined reference to `rust_int'
clink.c:(.text+0x3a): undefined reference to `rust_bool'
clink.c:(.text+0x83): undefined reference to `rust_char_star'
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
~/dev/rust/learn/clink$
```

This is where I am a little confused. I thought when you tell rustc that the crate-type is static that it includes all dependencies, but I guess that is not the case.

Clearly I am missing a step. I would prefer that rustc include all bindings so I can just use a simple command to clang to produce an executable.

Answer (score 1):

I was missing the standard library bindings. After a little more Googling I found a few links that were helpful:

- [Running Rust's output LLVM with Clang](https://www.reddit.com/r/rust/comments/7slfw9/running_rusts_output_llvm_with_clang/)
- [Running LLVM file, generated with rustc, with clang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48430136/running-llvm-file-generated-with-rustc-with-clang)

It turns out I just needed to know where the Rust standard object file was. Running the following is a solution:

> ```
> ~/dev/rust/learn/clink$ rustc --crate-type staticlib rustlink.rs
> ~/dev/rust/learn/clink$ clang clink.c -o test ~/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libstd-89cf9eb8d404bb7b.so -L . -lrustlink
> nick@Void:~/dev/rust/learn/clink$ ./test
> 5
> False
> "Testing"
> Did I get here?
> ~/dev/rust/learn/clink$
> ```

I added a line "Did I get here" because when I was originally successful in compilation, the program segfaulted before completion. I was trying to figure out if it was the `CString` printing that was causing it or not. Turns out I had a sort of double free condition. I will add the revised Rust code at the very bottom for completeness.

As a second solution, and more to my liking, you can use an object file:

> ```
> ~/dev/rust/learn/clink$ rustc --emit obj --crate-type staticlib rustlink.rs --verbose
> ~/dev/rust/learn/clink$ clang clink.c -o test rustlink.o ~/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libstd-89cf9eb8d404bb7b.so 
> ~/dev/rust/learn/clink$ ./test
> 5
> False
> "Testing"
> Did I get here?
> ~/dev/rust/learn/clink$
> ```

They both result in the same output, and I can't really say if one way is better than the other. It depends on what your requirements are in development.

Last. My original code above for rustlink.rs was wrong. I learned that using a `CString` that is bound to a raw pointer is pretty much a bad idea. It needs to allocate its own memory, I think, in most circumstances. This is due to `drop`. I changed the `rust_char_star` function from the original post to the following.

> ```
> #[no_mangle]
> pub extern "C" fn rust_char_star(c: *const c_char) {
>     let ch = unsafe { CStr::from_ptr(c) };
>     let str_printable = CString::from(ch);
>
>     println!("{:?}", str_printable);
>     println!("Did I get here?");
> }
> ```

That prevents what is effectively a double free.

Comment: I had the exact same problem but was using gcc instead of clang to link the object files. Your solution worked for me!